# How prove in Hilbert's sequent calculus

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, sequent-calculus

Hilbert's sequent calculus axiom:

(1.1)$A\supset (B\supset A)$

(1.2)$(A\supset (B\supset C))\supset((A\supset B)\supset (A\supset C))$

(2.1)$A\supset (A\vee B)$

(2.2)$B\supset (A\vee B)$

(2.3)$(A\supset C)\supset((B\supset C)\supset ((A\vee B) \supset C))$

(3.1)$(A\wedge B) \supset A$

(3.2)$(A\wedge B) \supset B$

(3.3)$(C\supset A)\supset((C\supset B)\supset (C \supset (A\wedge B))$

(4.1)$(A\supset B)\supset((A\supset \neg B)\supset \neg A)$

(4.2)$A\supset (\neg A \supset B)$

(4.3)$A\vee \neg A$

and there is a rule "Modus Ponens".

If $A$ and $A\supset B$ is either a formal theorem, then $B$ is also a formal theorem.

I am puzzling with proving (Question).

(Question)$(A\supset B)\supset((C\supset A)\supset (C\supset B))$

How prove (Question)?

Comment: You should also add more context on your efforts.

Comment: As a hint, the formula is provable using 1.1, 1.2, and modus ponens. You can safely ignore the rest of the calculus.

Comment: This deductive system doesn't look like a sequent calculus to me.

Comment: Do you know the Deduction Theorem for *Hilbert-style* propositional calculus, i.e. if $A \vdash B$, then $\vdash A \supset B$ ? In this case, the suggestion of Emil can be easily applied, starting from the following instance of your *(1.1)* : $(A \supset B) \supset (C \supset (A \supset B))$ and a suitable instance of your *(1.2)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Hilbert-style calculus with *modus ponens* (**no** sequent calculus) and without Deduction Theorem, we have :

*Ax 1.1)* $P \supset (Q \supset P)$

*Ax 1.2)* $(P \supset (Q \supset R)) \supset ((P \supset Q) \supset (P \supset R))$

Now the deduction :

*1)* $(A \supset B) \supset (C \supset (A \supset B))$

is an instance of *Ax 1.1*, with $P := (A \supset B)$ and $Q := C$

*2)* $(C \supset (A \supset B)) \supset ((C \supset A) \supset (C \supset B))$

is an instance of *Ax 1.2*, with $C$ in place of $P$, $A$ in place of $Q$ and $B$ in place of $R$

Let $X := (C \supset (A \supset B))$ and let $Y := ((C \supset A) \supset (C \supset B))$
, so that 2) is : $(X \supset Y)$

*3)* $(X \supset Y) \supset ((A \supset B) \supset (X \supset Y))$

is an instance of *Ax 1.1* with $(X \supset Y)$ in place of $P$ and $(A \supset B)$ in place of $Q$

*4)* $((A \supset B) \supset (X \supset Y))$

by 2), 3) and MP

*5)* $((A \supset B) \supset (X \supset Y)) \supset ((A \supset B) \supset X) \supset ((A \supset B) \supset Y)$

is a (very complicated) instance of *Ax 1.2* with $(A \supset B)$ in place of $P$, $X$  i.e. $(C \supset (A \supset B))$, in place of $Q$ and $Y$ i.e. $((C \supset A) \supset (C \supset B))$ in place of $R$

*6)* $(A \supset B) \supset Y$

i.e.

$(A \supset B) \supset ((C \supset A) \supset (C \supset B))$

from 5, 4 and 1 with MP twice.

**If** we have the Deduction Theorem, the proof is much simpler :

*a)* assume $(A \supset B)$

*b)* $(A \supset B) \supset (C \supset (A \supset B))$   --- as above : is an instance of *Ax 1.1*

*c)* $(C \supset (A \supset B))$    --- from a) and b) by MP

*d)* $(C \supset (A \supset B)) \supset ((C \supset A) \supset (C \supset B))$   --- as above : is an instance of *Ax 1.2*

*e)* $((C \supset A) \supset (C \supset B))$   --- from c) and d) by MP

In this way we have :

$(A \supset B) \vdash ((C \supset A) \supset (C \supset B))$

Now we can apply the Deduction Theorem and get :

*f)* $\vdash ( (A \supset B) \supset ((C \supset A) \supset (C \supset B)) )$.